# How do Twitter's Rate Limits function when issuing requests to different endpoints?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I've been trying to figure out how to buckets my requests for multiple endpoints.

Say for example I have 4 endpoints that I'm querying. According to the docs, these are the rate limits in 15 minute windows: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits

- friends/list: 75
- followers/list: 15
- statuses/mentions_timeline: 75
- statuses/user_timeline: 900

However, when I make a few hundred requests to `statuses/user_timeline` it seems I get a rate limit error on `followers/list`. I'm not sure how the requests are bucketed. Do the `user_timeline` requests count towards `followers/list`.

Also, is there an automated way of managing Twitter API calls in Node?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints each have separate limits, so there should be no change to the queries on the `followers/list` endpoint as a result of hitting `statuses/user_timeline` separately. One of the best ways to check (for read endpoints like these) is to query the `x-rate-limit-limit` and `x-rate-limit-remaining` HTTP headers on your requests.